# How users should pass a token for oauth2

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm trying to get my head around adding oauth2 to an API I've created.
Currently, I've got calls that require a unique key in the URL e.g.
https://apilocation.com/api/{unique_key_here}/action/

I've just added the ability for someone to get an access_token using:
https://apilocation.com/api/{unique_key_here}/oauth2/token
and a username + secret key
which works fine and returns the token in a JSON array.

https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/
is what I'm following

Where I'm stuck is how to best get them to use the access and pass it in their calls to the API.  I could get them to get the token each time they want to use the API and then include that in all their calls so I can validate but that seems clunky.  The background is built on PHP and MySQL and I want it to be easy for people who aren't very used to coding to be able to make calls.

I've looked at the following:
passing in the request url
passing it as a post var
partially as a header but felt it was clunky for a new user

Comment: Witch you have described is not a oAuth2 flow. See the [oAuth2 docs](https://oauth.net/2/)

Comment: @Max yes, I missed an obvious part and have included a link to what I'm following though if it isn't oauth2 then fair enough but would like to know where I'm going wrong

Comment: @Alan Doolan Including the access token in the header like this `Authorization: Bearer token_here` each time you make a call to the API is the standardized method

Comment: @Cocest so should they be passing their username and secret key to get a token and then pass that for all calls in the header?  so is there a clean way to handle when the token runs out of time?

Comment: @Alan, Once the user obtains the access token, the person no longer need to pass user name and secret key, what is pass is the obtained token. If the token expired, the user can obtain a new token using `refresh token` depending on `Authorization flow` you implemented. If you want to retain user info learn about using `JWT`

Comment: @Cocest ok, I didn't add a refresh token yet but have come across it.  I didn't quite understand what needed to be done with that but will research.  but for clarity with my current setup they should be following the current steps:  1. get a client_id and secret_key from me  2. pass them to the oauth token call and get their token (and refresh token) 3. each time they use the api they pass the access_token (and refresh_token??) in the header and they shouldn't need to pass their client_id and secret_key again?  doesn't that just equal giving them a unique key at the start and them passing it?

Comment: @Alan There is a big difference between access token and client credentials (client_id and client_secret). An access token is short-leaved to mitigate an attack with a stolen token and client credentials is confidential and should be kept secret (only pass client credentials on a secured network). An access token is only what is needed to access `resource server`. The refresh token is used when the token has expired because it skips the redirection flow and obtains a new token from `authorization server`, and when stolen doesn't contain the client credentials and can be revoked.

Comment: @Alan For a detailed explanation, check out the link: [https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/)